# How do I ensure a double input in a TextField? (Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, textfield

New to Swift here. I'm making an application that will take a price from the user through a TextField, and calculate the tip. In order for it to not crash, I want it to only take a valid double but I'm unsure on how to do so.

Button function handling this process:

```
@IBAction func calculate_eighteen_perc(_ sender: Any) {
    let bill:Double = round(Double(user_bill_input.text!)! * 100) / 100.0
    let tip:Double = round(bill * 0.18 * 100) / 100.0
    let total:Double = bill + tip
    result_display.text = "Tip Amount: $\(tip); Total: $\(total)"
}
```

The cases that will crash the program, to my knowledge, are:

1. Whitespace before number.
2. Any non-number character in input.
3. Multiple decimal points.
4. Empty input (nil).

Is there a way to handle this gracefully, without writing a condition to check each case?
Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You have to create a function for validating the user input for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally want to avoid forced unwrapping for the reason you identified -- invalid entries will crash your app. Double(user_bill_input_text) won't crash your app by itself if the user's input isn't a Double. The return type of casting to Double from a String is an optional Double, and its value will simply be nil if one of the invalid entry conditions you identified occurs.

Then, you can use a guard statement, in which the rest of the function will execute if the value is non-nil. If it is, you can set an error condition and exit the function safely.

```
@IBAction func calculate_eighteen_perc(_ sender: Any) {
    let input = Double(user_bill_input_text)
    guard let input = input else {
        print("Invalid entry. Try again.")
        return
    }
    // put the rest of the code that you only want to execute if the input 
    // is a valid Double here
}
```